# JPA Join on specific field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, specifications

I have this scenario:

**User** and his related **UserRole** entity classes, as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
   private int id;

   @Column(name="USERNAME", unique=true, nullable=false, length=255)
   private String username;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
   private List<UserRole> userRoles;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_role_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int userRoleId;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=45)
    private String role;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="username", nullable=false)
    private User user;
}
```

Now, I need to query all users that have a specific role. I'm trying making join with JPA Specifications, like that:

```
Join<User, UserRole> join = root.join(User_.userRoles);
Expression<String> match = join.get(UserRole_.role);                    
Predicate predicate = builder.equal(match, "ROLE_USER");
```

The problem is that the generated join will be between User.**id** and UserRole.**username** and the query will obviously have no results.

```
select count(user0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from USER user0_ inner join
user_roles userroles1_ on user0_.ID=userroles1_.username where 
userroles1_.role='ROLE_USER'
```

I need instead to have the on clause both on **username** fields:

```
... from USER user0_ inner join
    user_roles userroles1_ on user0_.USERNAME=userroles1_.username ...
```

I noticed that there is the **.on** method of Join class who:

> Modify the join to restrict the result according to the specified ON
>   condition. Replaces the previous ON condition, if any. Return the join
>   object

Is this the correct approach? If so, how could I implement that?

```
Join<User, UserRole> join = root.join(User_.userRoles).on(????);
```

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**:
`UserRole_` metamodel class

```
@StaticMetamodel(UserRole.class)
public class UserRole_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserRole, Integer> userRoleId;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserRole, String> role;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserRole, User> user;
}
```

`User_` metamodel class:

```
@StaticMetamodel(User.class)
public class User_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, Integer> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, String> username;
    public static volatile ListAttribute<User, UserRole> userRoles;
}
```

Comment: You could do it using the JPA 2.1 `ON` clause (EclipseLink supports this in its latest versions), but you'll have to use JPQL and not Criteria.
As long as i'm concerned, i don't see why your Critera request won't work, because the column `username` of the table `user_roles`  will contain the user id and not its name (since the user id is the `@Id` column of `User`)

Comment: thank you @clapsus Could you post an example of that please?

Comment: @clapsus the column `username` of `user_roles` contains the username of the user, so the on clause should be between `username` columns of the two tables

Comment: how do you fill your table? With JPA, or by hand (sql script...ect) ?

Comment: with JPA, it's a kind of user provisioning application @clapsus

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Good One! It solves the problem! Thank you.

Comment: I've created an answer from my comment.

Comment: I also did it! :D @TobiasLiefke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `referencedColumnName`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="username", referencedColumnName="username", nullable=false)
private User user;
```

With only `@JoinColumn(name="username")` you tell Hibernate that the join column in `user_roles` is named `username` - but it still expects that it contains the values of the `@Id` property of User. If you create the DDL for your schema you will see that Hibernate generates a number column for `user_roles.username`.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, you should check what the user_roles.username column contains, because by default, it contains the `@Id` column of the referenced entity, here the referenced entity is User, and its @Id column is `id` (in your schema: `ID`) and not `username` (in your schema: `USERNAME`).

Although, here's an example of how to write  what you described here:

> The problem is that the generated join will be between User.id and
>   UserRole.username and the query will obviously have no results. I need
>   instead to have the on clause both on username fields:

In JPQL (using JPA 2.1)

```
// get entity manager as 'em'
TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u INNER JOIN UserRole ur ON ur.user = u.username WHERE ur.role = 'ROLE_USER'", User.class);
List<User> results = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: `user_roles.username` contains exactly the username of the user. That's the table where spring security will query for authorithies `.authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?")`. I don't want to change the table definition until it is not necessary, and need to use JPA Specification to generate a `Predicate` if it is possible. Really there's not a way for doing that?

Comment: I updated my answer with one possible solution, you could try this.

Comment: where to implement getUsername()? `UserRole_` is a _metamodel_ class and its properties are instances of `Attribute<X, T>`. I can't figure out what you mean. Could you please explain that better?

Comment: this is the UserRole_ metamodel class: 
`@StaticMetamodel(UserRole.class)
public class UserRole_ {
 public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserRole, Integer> userRoleId;
 public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserRole, String> role;
 public static volatile SingularAttribute<UserRole, User> user;
}`
Yes, i know what the generics mean. Anyway, `User` entity class has getters and setters for each attribute, so already has _getUsername()_

Comment: wrong try...it generates:  `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidWithClauseException: with clause can only reference columns in the driving table [select generatedAlias0 from User as generatedAlias0 inner join generatedAlias0.userRoles as generatedAlias1 with generatedAlias1.user=generatedAlias0.username where generatedAlias1.role=:param0]`

Comment: Yeah after further investigation, i could'nt find a way to do it using Criteria API.

Comment: "ur.user" is a User and u.username is a String, hence JPQL is wrong.